# .addclass when click! and when click again! .removeclass - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `h1` `button`, has a label `click to toggle` and a class name `clickMe`, I want it! when I click the `click to toggle` it add class example `active` class so i can style it differently from the `class` `clickme` which is my default style  and when I click again the class will automatically remove. I try it to my self but unfortunately, I have no luck to make it work. the **js code** below with the demo is my current revision.

this my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gSALD/6/)**

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.clickMe').click(function () {
                  $('.content').slideToggle('2000', function () {
                      // Animation complete.
                  });
              });
        $('.clickMe').addClass('active').removeClass('active');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: What's the question? And what's the point of adding a class and immediately removing it?

Comment: Then see the answer given by @mostafaznv http://jsfiddle.net/gSALD/9/

Comment: FYI, you don't need your outer function unless you have things in it you're doing outside of `ready` that you haven't shown; instead:: `jQuery(function($) { /* ...use $ for jQuery here... */ });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use toggleClass() for that.

i changed your code

## demo

---

**jquery:**

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.clickMe').click(function () {
            $('.content').slideToggle('2000', function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 Note that if `.clickMe` matches multiple elements, though, this will toggle **all** of them. `$(this).toggleClass('active');` will toggle only the one actually clicked.

Comment: @mostafaznv: Fantastic attitude deleting your second answer and editing this one instead, nice one. You're going to be a valuable addition to SO. Just be sure you always explain (one-line answers are rarely useful). Good job guessing what the OP was asking prior to their edit. Best,

Answer (score -3):

Did you try that :

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.clickMe').click(function () {
                              $('.content').slideToggle('2000', function () {
                      // Animation complete.
                  });
                    $('.clickMe').toggleClass('active');
              });
    });

})(jQuery);
```